# How do I use the count function to count instances of different elements in one column

Tags: sql

I am working with a Dungeons and Dragons type database and I need to count the number of each type of class name. i. e. a table called characters and it contains multiple instances of Druid, Bard, Cleric, etc.  How would I go about counting each of these classes.

To be more specific I have 2 tables called rpg.pcs & rpg.npcs that represent playable characters & non playable respectively; or I have rpg.characters that contain characters inserted w/ a class ID and a rpg.classes that contains each type of class with a class ID.  I tried unioning the first two and counting each instance of each character with

```
SELECT char_id, name, COUNT(class) level
FROM rpg.pcs
UNION
SELECT char_id, name, level
FROM rpg.npcs;
```

and I also tried joining the second two tables and counting that way w/

```
SELECT cl.name, COUNT(cl.name)
FROM rpg.characters AS ch INNER JOIN
     rpg.classes AS cl
     ON ch.class_id = cl.class_id;
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong or what I should be doing?

DESIRED RESULTS

`Druid 5
Bard 2
Cleric 15`
etc...

Cant give a database tag because a professor made it up and it is unable to be used from anywhere other than campus network.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your second query it seems you are just missing a group by clause -

```
SELECT cl.name, COUNT(cl.name)
FROM rpg.characters AS ch INNER JOIN
     rpg.classes AS cl
     ON ch.class_id = cl.class_id
GROUP BY cl.name;
```

For rest please provide sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you need for both NPC and PC tables, your first query is close, but not quite there. Try this:

```
DECLARE @dd_pcs TABLE
(
    char_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name NVARCHAR(100),
    class NVARCHAR(100),
    level INT
)

DECLARE @dd_npcs TABLE
(
    char_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name NVARCHAR(100),
    class NVARCHAR(100),
    level INT
)

INSERT INTO @dd_pcs (name,class,level) VALUES
('name1','Druid',10),
('name2','Bard',9),
('name3','Druid',11)

INSERT INTO @dd_npcs (name,class,level) VALUES
('name4','Druid',5),
('name5','Bard',7),
('name6','Druid',2)

SELECT class,COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @dd_npcs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM @dd_pcs
) t1
GROUP BY class
```

OUTPUT:

```
class   ClassCount

Bard    2
Druid   4
```